# Twilio SHAKEN/STIR product phone number adding to business profile

Tags: twilio

While we add Business Information to Secondary Business Profile during the SHAKEN/STIR product configuration, can we able to assign a non-twilio telephone number (that not exists in twilio) to the Business Profile ?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you a direct customer? Or an ISV (independent software vendor)? You are considered a direct customer if your employees are responsible for making the calls. This includes BPOs. You are considered an ISV (independent software vendor) if your customers are responsible for making the calls using your product. Furthermore, do you have subaccounts?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actuially the party is an ISV with sub accounts for every customers to this party. Every customer wants to use their office phone as the caller id and they dont want any further verification code inputs on phone validation. They will just input the business information and add phone number and then the calls for their office team to end users will happen with their office telephone as caller id.

Comment: Ok. To my limited knowledge, you can't assign a non-Twilio telephone number to the Business Profile. Here you're entering in the Phone Number SID, which you can only have if it's a Twilio number. This can be found in the Console, go to your Dashboard for your Customer Subaccount. In the Project Info section, click on See all phone numbers, then click on a phone number to find the SID.

Comment: Ok. But in cases like a party selling its app to various customers, how we can allow the customers to use their work telephone as caller id, without validations ? any other methods or special plan twilio offering ? any kind of information if you have, please share. thanks